# Why am i getting WHITE SCREEN on VIVO Phone after installing an app?

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on V2025 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
I/flutter (25284): Observatory listening on ************************************

If i simply run, i get a white screen.
After some google, i found the solution as ---- flutter clean and flutter upgrade then i can see my app running smoothly.
if i make any changes then, i again get the same white screen.
Everytime, i make changes in the app. i have repeat flutte clean and flutter upgrade.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: white / gray-ish screen is a crash in the app

Comment: Frankly speaking, its not a crash on my case.  If i do, flutter clean and flutter upgrade, my case is sloved.  Everytime i make a change in my app, i have to always do flutter clean and flutter upgrade. If i simply click run, then i get white screen in case of VIVO phone.